# Laravel Access Control with Model Objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to restrict the access to some parts of the application depending on the user logged in. I mean for example to let a user edit only its own posts on a blog application.

Is there a better approach than in every function of the controller, if the user is not the owner of the required post, redirect to some error page?

For example if my routes are `/post/{post_id}/edit`, `/post/{post_id}/preview`, `/post/{post_id}/delete`, can I somehow declare a general function in the PostController like:

```
if(Post::find($post_id)->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
    return View::make('access-error');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can do something like this:

```
public $check = ['edit', 'preview', 'delete'];

public function callAction($method, $parameters) {
    if(in_array($method, $this->check, true) && 
    $post_id = $parameters['post_id'] &&
    Post::find($post_id)->user_id != Auth::user()->id) {
        return View::make('access-error');
    }

    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what I'm looking for. Is there any other things to do to make this work? Just by including this function in the controller seems to not work. Do you have any reference on how to properly use callAction function? Thanks! :)

Comment: var_dump the $parameters, maybe the array key for post_id is different. This code actually works for me. EDIT: Also make sure your methods names in $check are valid

Comment: The better approach will be to use [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0). It utilises the full power of Laravel. And its far more better approach than mentioned by @crapProgammer.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a 401 error and catch it elsewhere to display a custom page

```
App::abort(401);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-404-errors

Comment: What I need is a general method to put in the controller to throw that error, not how to throw the error itself